# Rough estimate of tile cutter wheel durability

Tags: tile, cutting

Can somebody give a rough estimate about the lifetime of a tile cutter wheel? I own a Sigma 3b4  which works with the [14A wheel](http://www.toolacademy.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=380).

Comment: What kind of tile are you cutting? On score and snap cutters like this the wheels have lasted me years when kept cleaned and oiled.

Comment: Normal tiles, nothing special. Are you speaking about oiling the shaft of the wheel?

Comment: Actually a drop on the cutting wheel surface. I was taught to do this with glass cutters years ago and started using when cutting porcelain tiles but I don't usually use on clay.

Answer (score 2):

estimated [tile cutter](https://www.toolacademy.com/product/sigma-tile-cutter-37-cm-95/) lifetime is nearly 10years, but [Sigma 3b4](https://www.toolacademy.com/product/sigma-26-tile-cutter-cm-67/) lifetime is 8 years.
[image]

Comment: As you say, estimate. Depends on how frequently used/abused, how maintained, phase of Jupiter...

Comment: Good point, @keshlam, however the OP asked for a _rough estimate_, which this provides. (Direct from the mfgr - wonder why the OP didn't look there...)

Comment: Point granted, I suppose.